# unable to open a file

Tags: c++, file, get, fstream

I'm try to open file, a text file.

I've include string and fstream.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
```

This is the code I have in my program, but every time I run the program, it says "unable to open file".

```
float unscreen()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the screen help area" << endl;


    cout << "\n" << endl;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("unsreen.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(myfile, line))
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "unable to open file";


    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Press 0 for further action or press 9 to exit." << endl;
```

Do i need to change something on the file, I got the file on the directory.

Comment: Are you sure the file is named `unsreen.txt` and not `unscreen.txt`? The name of you function seems to indicate the later=)

Comment: I'm going to find another solution to open file.

Comment: Check that your program has enough permission to open the file, if using windows run your program as an admin.

Comment: You shouldn't need "another solution" - this will work if you use the correct file name. Is it in the same directory as your executable?

Comment: After few hours messing the code, the file open now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have unsreen.txt in projects\projectname\projectname

This same code is working fine. If it still doesn't work for you then delete the file comment all this code and add

```
ofstream myfile("unsreen.txt");
myfile<<"sdafe";
myfile.close();
```

Then open the file, add what you want to add then delete this code and replace with older one.